# GMRES algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods

Can you suggest me a reference (besides Wikipedia) where the GMRES (Generalized minimal residual method) algorithm is explained in full detail, in a nice and easy way to understand? A clearly written, easy to follow resource would be wonderful.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 5):

It was developed by [Yousef Saad and Martin Schultz](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0907058). It can be found [in Saad's book, chapter 6.5](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme324/saad.pdf).

Comment: with Schultz, in SIAM J. Sci. Stat. Comput., vol.7, no.3, July 1986.

Comment: See also [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589281).

Comment: Thank you, will look into all the posted resources and report back.

Answer (score 4):

Bau and Trefethen's *Numerical linear algebra* is a very enjoyable read.

Comment: @Chris: Don't forget to upvote!

Comment: But this book doesn't appear to have a good handle on GMRES. I couldn't understand how to form $Q_n$ out of $Q_{n-1}$ at the $n$-th step of Arnoldi iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Read the book

Krylov solvers for linear algebraic system

Of the authors: Charles George Broyden and Maria Teresa Vespucci

This book treat all the algorithms that are the state of the art in linear system solution